# creating circular motion blur in css or svg

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters, css-filters

I have an  image as a preloader image for my site, and I want to apply circular motion blur to it, but - there seems to be non out of the box, or is there?

Could I use one of SVG's filter primitives (like feConvolveMatrix or feColorMatrix) to achieve that?

Comment: I'm thinking you mean something like the spin blur filter from Photoshop? This is not possible with SVG Filters.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably achieve a reasonable facsimile of circular motion blur with a carefully crafted combination of filter primitives. You would need to use `feDisplacementMap` to do the rotation part.

https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObject/filters-displace-01-f.html